# Show the convergence of a sequence using a convergent sequence in a metric space

Tags: sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

1. Let $X$ a metric space with metric $d$ and let $P \subset X$ not empty.
2. Let $f :X \to \mathbb{R}$ a function and define $f(x) = \inf\{d(x,y): y \in P\}$.
3. Let $(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ a convergent sequence with limit $L$.

I want to prove that $f(x_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ converges to $f(L)$.

Here are my ideas. I know that 
$$\overline{P} = \{ x \in X: \inf\{d(x,y) : y \in P \} = 0 \}, $$
Where $\overline{P}$ denotes the closure.
Further I know that for $x,y, z \in X$
$$d(x,z) \leq d(x,y) + d(y,z). $$
Intuitively it is clear what I want to proof, but I struggle with making it formal. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps the easiest approach is to suppose that $\langle f(x_n):n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ does not converge to $f(L)$.

- Show that on this assumption there are an $\epsilon>0$ and a subsequence $\langle x_{n_k}:k\in\Bbb N\rangle$ such that $|f(x_{n_k})-f(L)|\ge\epsilon$ for all $k\in\Bbb N$.
- Show that for any $x,y\in X$, $d(x,y)\ge|f(x)-f(y)|$.
- Use the first two points to get a contradiction.

The second point is the hardest. HINT: If $x,y\in X$ and $p\in P$, we have $d(x,p)\le d(x,y)+d(y,p)$; use this to show that $f(x)\le d(x,y)+f(y)$. Show similarly that $f(y)\le d(x,y)+f(x)$.